# How do I use "not in" correctly to identify an item is not in a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples comprised of an interface name and access list name. Like this:
`exempt_int_acl_tuple=[('(app)', 'access-list nonat'), ('(app2)', 'access-list nonat')]`

Sample config to search through is something like this:

```
config=['access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0','access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 192.168.15.0 255.255.255.0','access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.240','blah','blah blah','some more blah']
```

I have a list strings in which I look for a specific pattern. If the list matches the pattern, I add it to a new list called `exempt_acl`.

So my code looks like this:

```
exempt_acl=[]
for interface,acl_name in exempt_int_acl_tuple:
      for someline in config:
        acl_statement=acl_name+' extended permit ip '
        if (acl_statement in someline) and (someline not in exempt_acl):
          exempt_acl.append(someline)
```

In this case, the access list name in the tuple is repeated so the config file is searched for twice. So exempt_acl looks like this:

```
['access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 ', 'access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 192.168.15.0 255.255.255.0 ', 'access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.240 ']
['access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 ', 'access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 192.168.15.0 255.255.255.0 ', 'access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.240 ']
```

However, the same lines are added twice, and it is creating a list of lists, instead of a list of strings. I thought the boolean evaluation for `(someline not in exempt_acl)` would prevent the line being added a second time, but it is. What am I doing wrong? I am using `file.read().splitlines()` to read the config file in case that makes a difference.

Comment: What do you mean by pattern? Can you please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please add example data for ```config```.

Comment: What is `exempt_acl?`

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the problem, but if it's just duplicates showing up in the `exempt_acl`, Can you just `break` after `exempt_acl.append(someline)` or use a `set` instead of a `list` for `exempt_acl`?

Comment: I've added some sample configuration that I've used to test my code. The break statement in the `if` evaluation results in the last line (containing 1.1.1.1) to not be added, which is strange.
Using break in the if statement still seems to return a list of lists, instead of list of strings.

Comment: It looks like your `someline` is a list (with a single sting in it) instead of being a string.

Comment: Yes, `someline` is a list with a single string in it. I should probably convert it to a string, or I need to add another `for` loop to make it only add a single string to `exempt_acl`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a file named `config.txt` with these contents:

```
access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 192.168.15.0 255.255.255.0
access-list nonat extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.240
```

And `test.py` containing this:

```
exempt_acl = [('(app)', 'access-list nonat'),
              ('(app2)', 'access-list nonat'),
             ]

results = []
with open('config.txt') as config:
    for line in config:
        line = line.strip()
        for _,acl_name in exempt_acl:
            acl_statement = acl_name + ' extended permit ip '
            if line.startswith(acl_statement) and line not in results:
                results.append(line)

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

That should do what you're looking for, if I understand your question correctly.

---

I'm not sure exactly what you were doing in your original code base - the code in your question was definitely not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This code also works as expected:

```
config = [line.strip() for line in open('config.txt')]

results = []
for _, acl_name in exempt_acl:
    for line in config:
        acl_statement = acl_name + ' extended permit ip '
        if acl_statement in line and line not in results:
            results.append(line)

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Comment: That seems to return a list of lists with the same entry 3 times.

I read the config file as a list of strings. I then create a tuple comprising an interface and acl name. I use the acl name in the tuple to create a string that will match config lines.

The list creates fine, but I want to eliminate the duplicates without resorting to something like set.

Comment: If you run this *exact* code with this *exact* config.txt you will have three different entries - one for each line in the config. Are you trying to do something different?

Comment: Slightly different. I'm using the original file, which in addition to those three 'access -list xxx' lines has other lines too. These shouldn't matter, as they'd not match the pattern being looked for. I'll try again.

Comment: Tested it and you're right. Any chance you'd care to comment on why my code is not working please? I tried using my original method to read the lines in config in, and it seems to work fine too. It must be something to do with one of my loops.

Also, looks like your method nests the tuple within the configuration for loop instead of the other way around. I guess this way you only look at the configuration file once and the tuple multiple times.

Comment: @TheStupidEngineer I added an example with the order of the loops changed around and I still get the expected output. If you can provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then I can help you figure out why your code doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: I've edited it to provide what I think is an MCVE. I tested it, and bizarrely, it seems to work with no amendments to the previously 'broken' code. This list generation is a small part of a larger function, so I'll have to take a closer look at it.

Really appreciate your help @Wayne Werner

Comment: @TheStupidEngineer I don't know if you're in the habit of using source control yet, but you should most definitely use something like [Git](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html) or [Mercurial](http://hginit.com/). If you commit when something is broken, then commit when it's working it becomes pretty easy to see what you changed ;)

Comment: Hi there, yes, I do use Git for version control, but I am pretty new to it.

As things stand, it is not "broken" for my purposes, but it's resulting in redundant config being generated. It's something that turned up when I was trying to add a new feature, so it's not committed to production yet!

Answer (score 1):

To start with, de`list`ify `someline` by saying `someline = someline[0]`.

If lines still appear to be appended twice, it probably comes down to the ambiguity of the condition `if (acl_statement in someline)` .   If two lines are slightly different (e.g. different amounts of whitespace) but nonetheless *contain* the same `acl_statement`, both will be appended.

Comment: Thanks, I did think it was due to this, but if `someline` is appended straight from the config to the new list, and the new list then checked for  the new `someline` then should that not be a 1:1 match?

Comment: I recommend debugging by `print`ing each `acl_statement` as it is checked.

Comment: Yup, I tried that originally. The for loop seemed ok, but the checking for the existing line in the newly generated list on the subsequent iteration through the config file seemed to not work.

Comment: Ok, so debugging seems to show exempt_acl being initialised to an empty list once the first for loop runs again. How is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to why the configuration was being printed twice.

Main was calling the function twice. Once incorrectly (not mapping the function output to a value, but performing the printing involved in the debugging), and once correctly, hence not affecting output.

Thanks to all who assisted. I'm very grateful for your help, and I learned a few things too! The most important lesson for me was to formulate an MCVE before posting in the future.